# optimize source code to decrease time execution

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working on the next exercise from HackerRank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem?isFullScreen=false

So far I need to optimize my sourcecode in order to pass the tests related to time execution

This is my sourcecode:

```
class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'migratoryBirds' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
     */

    public static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
    // Write your code here
        int coincidences = 0;
        int maxValuesPerCategory = 0;
        //I'm using TreeMap because sort isthe key on this exercise
        Map<Integer, Integer> results = new TreeMap<>();
        List<Integer> targetKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //1. classifying values by coincidences
        for(Integer element: arr){
            coincidences = Collections.frequency(arr, element);
            results.put(element, coincidences);
        }

        /* 
        2. filtering categories by highest coincidences,
        if there are more than 1, choose the label with the lowest value
        example: 4=5; 3=5 ->output= 3
        */
        //getting the value with most coincidences
        maxValuesPerCategory = Collections.max(results.values());
        //iterate the map to identify which keys have the maxvalue
        Set<Integer> keySet = results.keySet();
        for(Integer key : keySet){
            if(results.get(key) == maxValuesPerCategory){
                targetKeys.add(key);
            }
        }
                
        //3. sorting the list ascending to obtain the lowest value
        Collections.sort(targetKeys);
        //get the first value (it should be the lowest label category)
        return targetKeys.get(0);
    }
}
```

I would like to ask you about suggestions how to optimize stages 2 and 3 because, from my point of view, the first stage is efficient in terms of execution but if you have suggestions about it please let me know.

Thanks a lot in advanced

Comment: "the first stage is efficient in terms of execution" It's not. `Collections.frequency` iterates the entire collection; so doing that inside a loop iterating the entire collection makes that quadratic. Plus, you're expecting the same element many times, so you're going to be doing the same work many times. There is a pretty easy way to make that linear...

Comment: If this code works (other than being too slow), you should ask over at [codereview.se].